# Data binding to a TreeView using HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'm trying to get the TreeView control in my application to properly bind to a tree of objects by setting its `ItemsSource` and `DataContext` properties. The tree visualizes as expected, but the `TreeViewItem`s data context seems to hold incorrect values.

For example, I have a tree that looks like this:

```
[-] Header
    [-] Contents
        [+] Item1
        [+] Item2
        properties
    [+] Dictionary
[-] MetaDictionary
    [+] TypeDef1
    [+] TypeDef2
properties
```

The items are bound to the objects' `Data.Name` value. However, if I click any item that is a child of `Header` and examine it in the event handler, its `DataContext.Data.Name` says `Header` (after appropriate castings). Same thing happens with `MetaDictionary` and its children.

This is a shortened version of my class:

```
    public class CFItemTreeNode
    {
        private CFItem data;
        public CFItem Data
        {
            get { return data; }
            set { data = value; }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<CFItemTreeNode> children;
        public ObservableCollection<CFItemTreeNode> Children
        {
            //set & get as above
        }
        private CFItemTreeNode parent;
        public CFItemTreeNode Parent
        {
            //set & get as above
        }
    }
```

And this is my XAML. I've been scouring SO and the net for several days and I've incorporated bits and pieces of various tutorials and questions into this Frankenstein of mine. I believe it's a problem with the hierarchical template, but that's as far as I've gotten.

```
<Window x:Class="SSLowLevelBrowser.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SSLowLevelBrowser"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="600"
        Width="800"
        MinHeight="100"
        MinWidth="200"
        Closing="MainWindowClosing">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <!-- A margin of 0 px left and 2 px top -->
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 2" />
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />
            <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="TVI_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.PreviewMouseMove" Handler="TVI_PreviewMouseMove" />
            <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.PreviewDrop" Handler="TVI_PreviewDrop" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="575*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="390*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="390*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ToolBar Name="menuBar" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True">
            <Button Name="buttonOpen" Click="OpenFile">Open file</Button>
        </ToolBar>
        <TreeView Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Name="treeView"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CFItemTreeNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Data.Name}"
                                   MouseLeftButtonDown="TBlock_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Data.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 Visibility="Collapsed"
                                 LostFocus="TBox_LostFocus"/>
                    </Grid>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="textOutput" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update 1.** Here are my event handlers:

```
private void TVI_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
{
    dragStartPosition = args.GetPosition(null);
    dragSource = args.OriginalSource;
}
```

```cs
private void TVI_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
{
    Point currentPosition = args.GetPosition(null);
    // If there is actual movement and a drag is starting
    if (dragInProgress == false &&
        dragStartPosition.X != -1 &&
        args.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
        Math.Pow(currentPosition.X - dragStartPosition.X, 2) +
        Math.Pow(currentPosition.Y - dragStartPosition.Y, 2) > 25)
    {
        dragInProgress = true;
        DragDropEffects de = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(
            (TreeViewItem)sender,
            new DataObject(typeof(FrameworkElement), dragSource),
            DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
}
```

```cs
private void TVI_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs args)
{
    if (dragInProgress && args.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(FrameworkElement)))
    {
        CFItemTreeNode dragSource =
            ((CFItemTreeNode)((FrameworkElement)args.Data.GetData(typeof(FrameworkElement))).DataContext);
        CFItemTreeNode dropTarget =
            ((CFItemTreeNode)((FrameworkElement)args.OriginalSource).DataContext);
        CFItemTreeNode sourceParent = dragSource.Parent;
        CFItemTreeNode targetParent = dropTarget.Parent;
        if (sourceParent != targetParent)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can only swap siblings.");
            dragInProgress = false;
            return;
        }
        int sourceIndex = sourceParent.Children.IndexOf(dragSource);
        int targetIndex = sourceParent.Children.IndexOf(dropTarget);

        if (sourceIndex != targetIndex)
        {
            if (sourceIndex < targetIndex)
            {
                sourceParent.Children.RemoveAt(targetIndex);
                sourceParent.Children.RemoveAt(sourceIndex);
                sourceParent.Children.Insert(sourceIndex, dropTarget);
                sourceParent.Children.Insert(targetIndex, dragSource);
            }
            else
            {
                sourceParent.Children.RemoveAt(sourceIndex);
                sourceParent.Children.RemoveAt(targetIndex);
                sourceParent.Children.Insert(targetIndex, dragSource);
                sourceParent.Children.Insert(sourceIndex, dropTarget);
            }
        }
        dragSource = null;
        dragInProgress = false;
        // Reset start position to invalid
        dragStartPosition = new Point(-1, -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your event handler code.

Comment: Updated the question with event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Add `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainWindow}` to your binding.

Comment: Oh my. I just realized the age of the question.

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately I no longer have access to the source to verify the solution.